# How to ONLY keep the latest window in KSQL?

Tags: ksqldb

I want to monitor the count of events happened in last 30 days. So I have used HOPPING WINDOW (size 30 days, advanced by 1 day) in KSQL, but it will generate total 30 windows for each group item, how can I write ksql script to only keep the latest window? Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE FEATURE1_INDIVID_APPLY_REJECTED_COUNT_HOPPING_30_DAYS_TBL AS \
SELECT INDIVID_REGION, WindowStart() AS WINSTART, COUNT(*) AS APPLY_REJECTED_COUNT \
FROM FEATURE1_INDIVID_APPLY_REJECTED_HACKTIME_STM  \
     WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 30 DAYS, ADVANCE BY 1 DAYS) \
WHERE INDIVID_REGION IS NOT NULL \
GROUP BY INDIVID_REGION;
```

Comment: Is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232400/in-ksql-how-to-select-max-window-record-after-windowing-and-group-by ? Can you explain why you want to keep only the latest window?

Comment: Yes, related. Because I want to monitor the count of events happened in past 30 days refreshed by every day.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a `HAVING` filter to filter out any windows with a historic  `WINDOWEND`, e.g.

```sql
CREATE TABLE FEATURE1_INDIVID_APPLY_REJECTED_COUNT_HOPPING_30_DAYS_TBL AS \
SELECT INDIVID_REGION, WindowStart() AS WINSTART, COUNT(*) AS APPLY_REJECTED_COUNT \
FROM FEATURE1_INDIVID_APPLY_REJECTED_HACKTIME_STM  \
     WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 30 DAYS, ADVANCE BY 1 DAYS) \
WHERE INDIVID_REGION IS NOT NULL \
GROUP BY INDIVID_REGION
HAVING WINDOWEND < UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

(Correct syntax at ksqlDB version 0.11)

Unfortunately, such a `HAVING` clause requires [Github issue 4397](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4397) to be fixed. Once ksqlDB supports `WINDOWEND` in the `HAVING` clause you should be good to go!

Comment: This is exactly the case where I am currently working on actually. When you think about HOPPINGs with SIZE 1 DAYS and ADVANCE BY 5 minute, I think number of windows are not in a good shape to provide a good performance. So really looking forward for this issue to be resolved.