# In KSQL, How to select max window record after windowing and group by?

Tags: ksqldb

```
ksql> CREATE TABLE HOPPING_TABLE AS SELECT ID, WINDOWSTART() AS WINSTART, COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM MY_STREAM HOPPING WINDOW (SIZE 30 DAYS, ADVANCED BY 1 DAYS) GROUP BY ID;

ksql> SELECT ID, WINSTART, CNT FROM HOPPING_TABLE;

id                    winstart        cnt
-------------------------------------------

874163197805291909    1547164800000    23
874163197805291909    1547424000000    11
874163197805291909    1547510400000    26
874163197805291909    1547683200000    12

660071199310134801    1545868800000    6
660071199310134801    1546560000000    7
660071199310134801    1547251200000    3
```

Now, I just care about the cnt of window with max winstart value for each `ID` grouped, how to achieve that by KSQL then? 
Considering above example (2 IDs grouped), I hope a table can be generated from above HOPPING TABLE with the following records:

```
id                    winstart        cnt
-------------------------------------------

874163197805291909    1547683200000    12

660071199310134801    1547251200000    3
```

Comment: Please post text as text - it makes it much easier to work with (e.g. copy and paste into answers/comments)

Comment: So are you looking to get `874163197805291909/12` and `660071199310134801/3` ? That is, the latest count for a given id? Your question isn't fully clear.

Comment: Thanks Robin, I edited my question to make it more clear, hope you can understand it now.